# How to add a quicklook generator in sandboxed application?

Tags: macos, cocoa, sandbox, quicklook

I have created a QuickLook Generator for my application and I copied the quicklook generator to this location `Containers/com.Aravindh.EgApp/Data/Library/QuickLook/QuickLookGenerator.qlgenerator` by using this following code.

```
    NSString *path1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"QuickLookGenerator" ofType:@"qlgenerator"];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSLibraryDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
    NSString *librayPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] path];
    librayPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Quicklook/QuickLookGenerator.qlgenerator",librayPath];
    if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:librayPath]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:path1 toPath:librayPath error:&error];
    }
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "“QuickLookGenerator.qlgenerator” couldn’t be copied because you don’t have permission to access “QuickLook”." UserInfo=0x101518250 {NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/Users/Aravindh/Desktop/EgApp/EgApp/build/Release/EgApp.app/Contents/Resources/QuickLookGenerator.qlgenerator, NSUserStringVariant=(
    Copy
), NSDestinationFilePath=/Users/Aravindh/Library/Containers/com.Aravindh.EgApp/Data/Library/Quicklook/QuickLookGenerator.qlgenerator, NSFilePath=/Users/Aravindh/Desktop/EgApp/EgApp/build/Release/EgApp.app/Contents/Resources/QuickLookGenerator.qlgenerator, NSUnderlyingError=0x10154dbb0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted"}
```

Whether I have to mention anything in the Entitlementes.plist? How to Install QuickLookGenerator in the SandBox Environment ?

Comment: I think you have to request access to that particular folder of the user... haven't seen any mention of quicklook generators in the sandbox permissions nor features. Maybe file a radar to add proper support?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need to copy the QuickLook plugin to `~/Library/QuickLook`. [If it's in `YourApp.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/Quicklook_Programming_Guide/Articles/QLArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005020-CH4-SW4) then the system will use it - this works with the sandbox because you don't need to do anything other than bundle the plugin with your app.

Comment: But I don't know how to add the quicklook generator in the path YourApp.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/. I tried to copy the file to the bundle path but no success.

Comment: I don't know how to create Library folder inside the app.

Comment: Don't do it at runtime, put the plugin there as part of your build process. You need a new Copy Files build phase in your target.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea to copy the files to appbundle. This is how I will do for ~/Library/QuickLook http://www.flickr.com/photos/80306719@N04/8287657102/in/photostream/lightbox/... Can you pls give some link on how to do this or explain in a way that I can understand.

Comment: Add a new "Copy Files" phase, then set it up like in this picture: http://www.evernote.com/shard/s197/sh/4c27c5e7-4318-4e6d-8ac0-a6b0aa902ab8/7f42b0318f9b7c93f49679a2f3fbd0eb